# UK visitor visa, do I provide information about the children we leave at home?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, children

I wish to know if anyone has an experience dealing with the following:
Husband and wife travelling together to the UK on a visitor visa for 1 month leaving their 7 and 12 year old children with their grandparents. Do I need to provide any documents relating to this situation with regards to our children?

Comment: UK authorities are mostly concerned about whether you'll leave at the end of your trip. I don't know whether you _need_ to document your children, but having two children in the care of grandparents is a compelling reason for you to return home. I'd find a way to include that information in your application.

Comment: This is an answer. ^

Comment: You most definitely need to list your dependent children whether they are going with you or not.

Answer (score 2):

You will be asked on the application form if there are dependents you’re temporarily leaving behind.

That section is exactly for the situation you describe.

Here is a screenshot of that section. You can add as many dependents as there are, and you will have to answer the following for each one of them.

---

[image]